# F# converting Seq to ICollection

Tags: f#

I have a seq of types

```
let rackStatusesPrototype : RackStatus seq
```

and now I want to assign it to a property which is from c# and is an ICollection type, but I am having a problem with it. I tried:

```
let test : ICollection<RackStatus> = rackStatusesPrototype :> ICollection<RackStatus>
```

But it says incompatible types. What can i do?

Comment: Do you need an `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`? They're not the same.

Comment: Side note: a sequence does not imply a collection--some sequences are infinitely long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to `open System.Linq` and invoke `ToList()` on your `rackStatusesPrototype` to have it converted to C# list, which implement ICollection.

Also F# Array implements ICollection, so `rackStatusesPrototype |> Array.ofSeq` should work as well. This may be preferred way, if you are having no other interactions with C# world.

Note, that F# list/set/map currently doesn't implement ICollection interface, but [adding it is planned](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/473).

Comment: `Array.ofSeq` or `Seq.toArray` seems to be the way to go IMHO